# How keep a CountDownTimer running when I press the back button

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer which updates a TextView, but when I press the back button it stops.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(600000, 100) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisUntilFinished);

        cron.setText(sf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
    }
};
```

How can I keep it running when I press the back button and the activity gets destroyed?

PS: I also start a GPS service when the timer starts, Is there a way to put the CountDownTimer in the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your timer needs to live beyond the lifecycle of your `Activity`, then it does not belong there.  You can certainly place it into a `Service`, or another object (like a singleton) that can stay resident in memory.

Comment: In this case, what is best: Singleton or Service?

Comment: Whatever fits your application.  There is no right or wrong.  Services are nice because the system can still manage their lifecycle, but that may be outside what your application wants to do as well.

Answer (score 1):

As prashant and Devunwire pointed out, you need to use a Service. Make sure you call `startService()` before binding to it, this causes the Service to stay alive even if the calling Activity is destroyed.

Make sure as well that the service stops itself with `stopSelf()` after the timer has finished and did whatever its supposed to do.

Comment: edit: I wouldn't override the back button since you can't close your app properly then.

Comment: I moved the timer to the Service, but the TextView is not updating. If I do cron.getText() in the service, It prints the value. But in the UI, it's not updating.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. If you get the value in the Service, you obviously have access to the widget...maybe you need to call `invalidate()` on the view. I used a Messenger to send messages from Service to Activity, but that app was not time-critical. You should try how fast it is. Tell me your results!

Comment: I used a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity to receive broadcasts from the Service and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to put the countdown timer in a Service. You can trigger the timer to start by sending an intent to the service. Also, you will have to use some mechanism  such as a callback or intent or messenger to relay the update time back to your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Override the back button and then make it behave like the home button. This way your activity is never destroyed. That said, I don't think this is considered "good practice."

To do what I'm saying you just place this into your activity class.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Whatever you do, as an optimization, you should make sure that the TextView is not updated if the TextView isn't visible on the screen. This should save battery life and probably prevent the creation of strings which will reduce garbage collections.