# How to start and show activity if my app was minimized on Android?

Tags: java, android, minimize

I create a new activity (when the timer ended), but it didn't show, because my app was minimized. How can I fix it?

Comment: **"How can I fix it?"** : Don't try to do this. If a user switches away from your app in order to use something else such as their phone, or another app then they basically don't wan't your app to show anything on their screen. It's their device - don't try to force them to use it the way you want them to use it. If you force an `Activity` from your app to be shown when they don't want to see it the user may well find it annoying and intrusive and may well uninstall your app.

Comment: my app has a timer and user can minimize app. But the timer will be finish and play some sound. User can't stop the sound, because activity with button "stop" didn't show.

Comment: Use `NotificationManager` to create a `Notification` to play the sound although don't make it a continuous sound. The user will get the `Notification` and be able to open your `Activity` from that.

Answer (score 1):

in your onResume of the parent activity from where you are firing the intent check if timer has finished or not. if yes then fire the intent from onResume() itself.

In this was if the app was minimised and user enters the app again he will directly navigated to the fired intent activity .

Comment: onResume didn't work, I firing my activity from CountDownTimer.

Comment: Try seeing this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546400/how-keep-a-countdowntimer-running-when-i-press-the-back-button might help you

Answer (score 0):

When your activity is minimized then all the operations that you perform in code are not executed as the application goes to PAUSE state. Better you start an SERVICE when your timer count ends and from that particular SERVICE do what you want to do.

Advantage:
Service will never go to halt state when your application is minimized and will keep on performing it's operations in the background.

Comment: I use CountDownTimer, but it didn't work if my was app minimize. But it work if my app finished. And onResum didn't work for me.